# Memorize recursive function value

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion

So I've got a recursive function that gets to the end of the last array and prints its value :

```
function recursive($array, $level = 1) {
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            if(is_array($value)){
                recursive($value, $level + 1);
            } else{
                echo 'LEVEL : '. $level . " ==> " . $key . ": " . $value, '<br>';
            }
        }
}
```

And thus displays the following example :

```
LEVEL : 2 ==> value: 10
LEVEL : 4 ==> key: A
LEVEL : 5 ==> value: 15
LEVEL : 7 ==> key: B
LEVEL : 8 ==> value: 45
LEVEL : 4 ==> key: C
LEVEL : 5 ==> value: 77
LEVEL : 7 ==> key: D
LEVEL : 8 ==> value: 18
```

At the end of the latest level (8 in this case) I want to display the values of its parents rather than everything- for example:

```
LEVEL : 8 ==> value: 10, key: A, value: 15, key: B, value: 45
LEVEL : 8 ==> value: 10, key: C, value: 77, key: D, value: 18
```

Knowing that 8 is just an example, there could be a lot more.

Input array example :

```
array = array(
    array(
        "value"=>"10"
        array(
            array(
                "key"=>"A",
                array(
                    "value"=>"15",
                ),
                ... etc
            ), 
           ... etc
        ),
    ),
);
```

Can someone help me with the algorithm to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show us the input array?

Comment: @Daniel1147 array is enourmous, I wrote a simple example, but with the levels you gotta get an idea of it. Each level is an array basically.

Comment: I think passing traverse path as an argument will help.

Comment: @Daniel1147 what do you mean? Could you develop please :)

Comment: I assume that if an array contains no array element, its the latest level. Right?

Comment: @Daniel1147 yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169874/discussion-between-daniel1147-and-fobujasa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add another argument $history in function recursive which tells the next level that what have been encountered.

```
<?php

function recursive($array, $level = 1, $history) {
    // this variable is to flag if there is an array element at current level.
    // if not, it will be latest level and output the line;
    $isLatestLevel = true;
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            recursive($value, $level + 1, $history);

            // an array element found; this is not the latest level;
            $isLatestLevel = false;
        } else{
            // create new entity to history
            $entity = $key . ": " . $value;
            $history[] = $entity;
        }
    }
    if ($isLatestLevel) {
        // output at the latest level
        // implode() means concate each history with ', ' between them
        echo "LEVEL : $level ==> " . implode(', ', $history) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$input = [
    'value' => '10',
    [
        [
            [
                'key' => 'A',
                [
                    'value' => '15',
                    [
                        [
                            'key' => 'B',
                            [
                                'value' => '45',
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                'key' => 'C',
                [
                    'value' => '77',
                    [
                        [
                            'key' => 'D',
                            [
                                'value' => '18',
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ],
];

recursive($input, 1, []);
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help !